# Understanding the Kolmogorov definition of conditional probability

Tags: probability

$$\begin{align}P(A|B)&=\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \\
&=\frac{P(A)\cdot P(B)}{P(B)}\\
&=P(A)
\end{align}$$

It seems that I assume that

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

incorrectly. I always thought that the probability of both events A and B occurring is the same thing as multiplying the probability of event A times the probability of event B. Can I get some clarification here since this rule seems to almost always work?

Comment: By definition, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Ah, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Giuseppe Negro pointed out in a comment, by definition $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ holds if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent.